# Returning a view in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot for practice. I am creating a sample website which have more than one view. I am using separate jsp for all views. Every jsp has some common code like all javascripts, css, and some other declaration inside . Is there a way that instead of returning entire jsp, I only return the body of each jsp and  and  are automatically added?

This may sound silly but there must be a way so we can remove so much boilerplate code.

Comment: Use thymeleaf with layouts, or use JSP and use an include filter (sitemesh did this in the early days but I doubt that there is a jakarta ee version for it).